# How to give the path of .mdb file kept in App_Data folder of the project

Tags: asp.net, access-data-project

this is my code to access the data from particular folder..
but i can't able to access the mdb database from my App_data folde..
plz help..

```
OleDbConnection a = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data   
Source=D:\\timetronix.mdb");
```

Comment: provide trusted connection value and username and password

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Answer (score 0):

try like this . [Connection strings Access](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)

```
OleDbConnection a = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\timetronix.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=somepass;");
```